# Determine constant for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a continuously differentiable function $f(x)$ that satisfies $\frac{d \ln f (x)}{d \ln x} = \beta$, with $f(0)=0$. Solving the differential equation, I obtain that $f(x)=c_{1} x^{\beta}$. Given that my initial condition is $f(0)=0$, I can determine the constant from $0=c_1 0^{\beta}$. Does this imply that $c_1=0$, or that the constant $c_1$ is not determined? Is there any case in which $c_1=1$?

Thanks!

Comment: $c_1$ is not defined by boundary condition $f(0)=0$. Solution is not unique.

Comment: If $\beta>0$, then $f(x) = c_1 x^\beta$ satisfies $f(0)=0$ for any constant $c_1$.  If $\beta<0$, then you must have $c_1 = 0$ as you said.  What about the last case, $\beta=0$?

Comment: Why is it the case that if $\beta < 0$, I must have $c_1=0$?